# Yii2 framework не создается кука

Tags: yii2

устанавливаю куку так

```
public function actionCountry(){
            $name=Yii::$app->request->get("name","Russia");
            $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

// добавление новой куки в HTTP-ответ
            $cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
                'name' => 'country',
                'value' => $name,
            ]));
           // $session=\Yii::$app->session;
            //$session->set('country',$name);
            //$session->remove('name');
            return $this->render('country',[
                'name'=>$name,
                'cookies'=>$cookies->getValue('country')
               // 'session'=>\Yii::$app->session->get('country')
            ]);
        }
    }
```

обрабатываю так

```
public function  actionIndex()
        {  $cookies= \Yii::$app->request->cookies;
            return $this->render('index',[
                'cookies'=>$cookies->getValue('country')
                //'session'=>\Yii::$app->session->get('country')
            ]);
        }
```

вывожу так

```
<p> Страна  <a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->CreateUrl(['country/country','name'=>$cookies]) ?>"> <?=$cookies?></a></p>
```

кука  не создается ну и соответствено не выводится. Откуда знаю что не создается web developer не выводит подскажите в чем проблема.
я уже дошел до того что уже просто создал через девелопер куку country и пытаюсь вывести через

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->request->cookies['country']);
```

выдает null

короче стандартную куку он через request выводит но через response не создает

Comment: По умолчанию в Yii2 $path = '/'; возможно в этом проблема?

Comment: @Invision  так я вроде path не трогаю

Comment: так я не вижу полную картину происходящего) то, что вы демонстрируете, с документацией совпадает. Нужно копать в сторону конфигурации сервера. $_COOKIE в сыром виде работает? Попробуйте продебажить методы в самом фреймворке, найти где отваливается.

Comment: @Invision  фишка в том что куки он создает там какаято кука с неудобоговоряшим параметром есть. И её находит. но вот создавать свои нет. Кроме того не создаются ещё и сессии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код корректен, проблема определенно в настройках или окружении.

- Проверьте `Yii2`. Используйте стандартный `response` от `yii2`. Если используете ваш собственный замените на время на стандартный и проверьте заработает ли со стандартным, без спецнастроек.
- Проверьте `php`. Если у вас не создается сессия возможно `session.use_cookies` равен `0`.
- Проверьте `веб-сервер`. Выполните простой php-файл только с установкой cookie и проверьте что она успешно создается.

Устанавливайте cookie и смотрите результат в консоли браузера:

```
<?php setcookie('foo','bar',time()+60*60*24*365, '/'); ?>
```